# How can use I Address Sanitizer in lli (LLVM)

Tags: linker, llvm, jit, address-sanitizer, lli

I would like to run a bitcode with address sanitizer argument, but I have a problem with that, if I run it, the segmentation fault will happen.

```
$cat sample.c
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  return 0;
}

$clang -emit-llvm -fsanitize=address -c -g sample.c

$lli sample.bc
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: lli sample.bc
0  lli                      0x000000010c112d9c llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 37
1  lli                      0x000000010c11319e SignalHandler(int) + 192
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff603e2b3d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2680280288
4  lli                      0x000000010be3ff74 llvm::ExecutionEngine::runStaticConstructorsDestructors(llvm::Module&, bool) + 310
5  lli                      0x000000010beac842 llvm::MCJIT::runStaticConstructorsDestructors(bool) + 388
6  lli                      0x000000010bb715c6 main + 8866
7  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff601f7ed9 start + 1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Try running with `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so.VER`. If it still fails with latest clang you can report bug in https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/

Comment: @yugr : thank you, It's solved my problem.but I'm a little confused, why clang will not link this automatically ?
and libasan is not available in llvm package in MacOS, I did use it from GCC.


`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libasan.dylib lli sample.bc`


do you know why it's not available in llvm ?

Comment: Hm, linking in GCC runtime may not be reliable so better stick with LLVM runtime. It seems to have a different name, can you search for library which looks like "clang_rt.asan.XXX" or something like this? I've added an answer in case you decide to +1 it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanitized code requires special runtime support which is implemented in Asan runtime library. `lli` does not load this library by default (because users normally don't need it) so you need to request it explicitly via `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so.VER`. Note `libasan.so` is GCC convention, for Clang you may need something like `libclang_rt.asan.XXX`. You can determine full library paths via

```
GCC_ASAN_PRELOAD=$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)
CLANG_ASAN_PRELOAD=$(clang -print-file-name=libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so)
```